# Select value and append number to it in one LINQ statement?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following two names in my database: `SMITH` and `SMITH1`

If a name exits in the database, I want to either append a 1 to it if only `SMITH` exits and if a name with a number already exits, I want to increment the numerical portion of the name.

Is it possible to do this in one LINQ statemnt?  Right now, I am doing:

```
string name = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}",first_name,middle_name,last_name).ToUpper();

//Check for duplicates
while(names.SingleOrDefault (d => d.Name== name) != null)
{
    //Get last char
    char lastChar = name[name.Length - 1];

    //Last char is number
    if(Char.IsNumber(lastChar))
    {
        name = name.Replace(lastChar,Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToInt32(lastChar) + 1));
    }
    else
    {
        name = (name + 1);
    }
}
```

Since I have the LINQ query in my while loop, will it do a select every time it has to cycle back around?

Also,  If anyone knows a way to make this more concise, but readable, that would be great?

This does work for names that have either no number or 1 - 9, but what happens when I get to 10, it will only replace the last character, in this case 0, how do I handle this?

Is there way to get the numerical portion in LINQ, so `SMITH12` would return `12`

Comment: @TimSchmelter - `while(names.SingleOrDefault (d => d.Name== name) != null)`. Isn't this a LINQ Query?

Comment: @TimSchmelter: He does have a LINQ-syntax statement as his `if` condition in his while loop.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - What is it properly called?

Comment: I thought it was a LINQ query because I am thinking that it will do something like a `SELECT Name FROM Table WHERE NAME = 'xxxxx'` which is a query to the database.

Comment: I would expect it would be far better for you to simply tell the user that their provided username is already used, and force them to select a new username.  You could even randomly modify their username (add a '1' or '9', substitute letters, etc) and give them a list of suggestions.

Comment: @Jeff - The user will provide a first name, middle name, and last name and I will create the other field based on those 3 fields.

Comment: I'm not sure why you've chosen to go that route, but I have provided an answer which may be helpful.

Comment: I'm with @Jeff on this. Your approach would require a lot of iteration whereas checking the username and suggesting alternatives (with suitable availability checks) is a far simpler approach. It also prevents your system from bleeding information relating to the number of users called 'JohnDoe' that are registered.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very naive, but easily readable way to do what you're looking to do:

```
//Check for duplicates
bool nameValid = names.SingleOrDefault (d => d.Name == name) == null;
int count = 1;
while(!nameValid)
{
    if( names.SingleOrDefault (d => d.Name == name + count.ToString()) == null )
    {
        name = name + count.ToString();
        nameValid = true;
    }
    else
    {
        count++;
    }
}
// name now contains a unique name
```

There are a number of ways to make this more efficient, some at the expense of readability.

I will leave optimization of this code as an exercise for you, should it need it.

Comment: I tried this. If I have something like JSMITH already, it returns JSMITH, not JSMITH1

Comment: Sorry about that, I misread your comment, then located a bug in the above code.

Comment: The initial setting of the bool was incorrect - it was set to 'true' (saying the name was good) only if there was a dupe.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be incorrect and doesn't compile.

This should work:

```
var sameNames = names
    .Where(n => n.Name.Length >= name.Length && n.Name.Substring(0,name.Length)==name);
if (sameNames.Any())
{
    var lastNameWithNumber = sameNames
        .Where(n => Char.IsDigit(n.Name.Last()))
        .Select(n => new { 
            n.Name, 
            Num = int.Parse(new string(n.Name.Reverse().TakeWhile(Char.IsDigit).Reverse().ToArray()))
        })
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Num)
        .FirstOrDefault();
    if (lastNameWithNumber != null)
        name = name + (lastNameWithNumber.Num + 1);
    else
        name = name + "2";
}
```

This checks if one or more objects' `Name` start with a given name. If that is true the first linq query checks if there are duplicates with numbers at the end. Then it will order by this number desc and picks the first(with the highest number). The new name will be the name + highestnumber+1. Otherwise it will just use the name + "2" since it's the second name.

Comment: I left out some parts, but it does compile and run. I have done it myself. I will try your solution out.

Comment: Your solution works, but I have a couple quetions:  1) How many times does this hit the database? 2) Does n.Name.Last() only check the last character, what if I want to check which characters at the end are numbers? Does that require regex?

Comment: If there will never be duplicates, is the OrderByDescending necessary?

Comment: @Xaisoft: What linq-provider are you sing, Linq-To-Sql? I'm suprised that it works at all with all that text and char methods, i've overlooked that you're using a database. The root query checkfs if there are duplicates at all. The `lastNameWithNumber` takes the duplicate with the highest numeric end, because of the  `OrderByDescending` it works with zero, one or multiple numeric duplicates.

Comment: I was trying it on an in-memory collection using Linqpad, but when I tried it against my actual database, I get the error: `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean IsDigit(Char)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`

Comment: @Xaisoft: I have no experiences with Linq-to-Entities but i thought that it doesn't support `SingleOrDefault` which is your only linq query. That's why i thought that you actually use Linq-to-Objects. Edit: But it's supported since .NET 4. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738474(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this.

```
IEnumerable<string> existingNames = ...;

string rawName = ...;

string finalName = (from suffix in Enumerable.Range(0, int.MaxValue)
                    let testName = rawName + (suffix == 0 ? "" : suffix.ToString())
                    where existingNames.All(n => n != testName)
                    select testName).FirstOrDefault();
```

Notes that `existingNames` is enumerated once per `suffix`. I would recommend using a HashSet for `existingNames` instead of an `IEnumerable<string>`.

```
HashSet<string> existingNames = ...;

string rawName = ...;

string finalName = (from suffix in Enumerable.Range(0, int.MaxValue)
                    let testName = rawName + (suffix == 0 ? "" : suffix.ToString())
                    where !existingNames.Contains(testName)
                    select testName).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

This will retrieve the next name (e.g if the most recent increment is NAME10, the next name will be NAME11):

```
int tmp;
var existingNames = from name in names
                let numericIndex = name.IndexOfAny(new char[] {'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0'}, 0)
                let subName = numericIndex > -1 ? name.Substring(0, numericIndex) : name
                let IndexAsString = numericIndex > -1 ? name.Substring(numericIndex) : "0"
                let index = int.TryParse(IndexAsString, out tmp) ? tmp : 0
                group new { subName, index } by subName into gs
                select gs;
var newNames = from existingName in existingNames
                select new { BaseName = existingName.Key, Index = existingName.Max(a => a.index) + 1 };
if (newNames.Any(a => a.BaseName == nameToAdd)) {
    // do your work to change the name
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines ought to do you:

Iterate over your enumerable list of names. For each such name,

- split it into its constituent components (a base name and an optional numeric suffix)
- toss any items where the base name doesn't match the desired name
- find the highest suffix value of the remaining set (which might be none).

If you found a max suffix, add 1 to that and append it to the desired name, otherwise return the desired name as-is.

**An example:**

```
private static readonly Regex rxNameSuffix = new Regex( @"^(?<name>.+)(?<suffix>\d*)$" ) ;
string GenerateName( string name , IEnumerable<string> existingNames )
{
    if ( string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name) ) throw new ArgumentException("name") ;
    int? maxSuffix = existingNames.Select( s => {
            Match m = rxNameSuffix.Match(s) ;
            if ( !m.Success ) throw new InvalidOperationException("that shouldn't have happened") ;
            string pfx = m.Groups["name"].Value ;
            int?   sfx = m.Groups["suffix"].Value.Length == 0 ? (int?)null : int.Parse( m.Groups["suffix"].Value ) ;
            return new Tuple<string,int?>( pfx , sfx ) ;
        })
        .Where( x => name.Equals( x.Item1 , StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) )
        .Aggregate( (int?)null , (acc,x) => {
            int? newacc ;
            if ( !x.Item2.HasValue ) return acc ;
            return !acc.HasValue || acc.Value < x.Item2.Value ? x.Item2 : acc ;
        }) ;
    int? suffix = maxSuffix.HasValue ? maxSuffix+1 : null ;
    return name + ( suffix.HasValue ? suffix.ToString() : "" ) ;
}
```